# Property of triangle center when barycentric coordinates are given

Tags: geometry, barycentric-coordinates

Trying to learn.. what may be interesting geometric properties of associated center of a triangle (sides $a,b,c$) whose  barycentric coordinates are:

$$\left(a^2+b^2-c^2,  b^2+c^2-a^2,  c^2+a^2-b^2 \right)$$

$$\left(ab-c^2, bc-c^2, ca-b^2 \right)$$

$$\left(\dfrac{1}{a},\dfrac{1}{b},\dfrac{1}{c}\right)$$

$$\left(\dfrac{1}{a^2},\dfrac{1}{b^2},\dfrac{1}{c^2}\right)$$

Appreciate pointer to any geometric software with three given barycentral functions as:
$$f(a,b,c), g(a,b,c), h(a,b,c)\;$$
to locate recognize/ interpret/characterize the centre.

Comment: May be GeoGebra could be a good tool.

Comment: Ok, but how can a tool let you always  guess a  geometric property?

Comment: It helps you to get an intuitive approach to the problem and since it is accurate and support easy modification it will allow you to verify and than this the case - GeoGebra has sliders and allow various modifications by just moving vortex points.

Comment: Can you please give one example to try it out, say the first one,  to invite some intuition. I promise before hand to accept it.

Comment: What are these values in 2D? I am not sure what is your problem? Are you interested in an example of a triangle? How to use sliders?

Comment: What are the vertices of the triangle? My understanding is that a point in 2D has a triplet associated with it. Are you looking for the 2D cartesian points that gives the above values? Do you have what points are resulting such triplets?

Comment: Edited to limit the scope of the question for a start.   If *(f,g,h)=(a,b,c)* functions set of a triangle is given in a particular case, then we should derive that this point referred to is the in-center of the triangle.

Comment: It may be worth noting that "the" way to search the Encyclopedia of Triangle Centers isn't via formulas but by calculating numerical coordinates of, eg, the [$6$-$9$-$13$ triangle](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/Search_6_9_13.html). Considering that there are scores of properties associated with any particular center, it would seem reading properties from coordinates isn't exactly "obvious"; rather, one would devise a dedicated barycentric relation for each property of interest, & then substitute-in to check whether a given set of coordinate functions satisfies that relation.

Comment: About example n°2 dealing with $(a^2-bc,b^2-ca,c^2-ab)$ see the recent answer I have given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4287417) using the concept of Hirst transform. It is the image of the incenter of the triangle by the Hirst transform.