# If $\frac{x^2-yz}{a^2-bc}=\frac{y^2-zx}{b^2-ca}=\frac{z^2-xy}{c^2-ab}$, prove that $\frac{x}{a}=\frac{y}{b}=\frac{z}{c}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving, ratio

> **Problem**: Let $a, b, c, x, y, z$ be real numbers
> such that $abc \ne 0$, $ ~ a + b + c \ne 0$, $~ (a^2 - bc)(b^2 - ca)(c^2 - ab)\ne 0$, $xyz\ne0$, $x+y+z\ne0$, $(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2\ne0$
> and $$\frac{x^2-yz}{a^2-bc}=\frac{y^2-zx}{b^2-ca}=\frac{z^2-xy}{c^2-ab} \ne 0.$$
> Prove that $$\frac{x}{a}=\frac{y}{b}=\frac{z}{c}.$$

The converse can be proved easily.

**My Attempt:**

$
\frac{x^2-yz}{a^2-bc}=\frac{y^2-zx}{b^2-ca}=\frac{z^2-xy}{c^2-ab}\\
\Rightarrow\frac{x^2-yz-y^2+zx}{a^2-bc-b^2+ca}=\frac{y^2-zx-z^2+xy}{b^2-ca-c^2+ab}=\frac{z^2-xy-x^2+yz}{c^2-ab-a^2+bc}\ [By\ Addendo]\\\Rightarrow\frac{x-y}{a-b}\cdot\frac{x+y+z}{a+b+c}=\frac{y-z}{b-c}\cdot\frac{x+y+z}{a+b+c}=\frac{z-x}{c-a}\cdot\frac{x+y+z}{a+b+c}\\\Rightarrow\frac{x-y}{a-b}=\frac{y-z}{b-c}=\frac{z-x}{c-a}\ \left[Considering\ (x+y+z)\ and\ (a+b+c)\ \neq0\right]
$

**Known Exceptional Counter-examples:-**

**Macavity**: $a=1, b=2, c=3, x=y=z$

**River Li**: $a = 1, b=2, c = -3, x = 7, y = 7, z = -14$

The conditions in the question have been edited to exclude exceptional counter-examples.

Comment: Okay, editing it!

Comment: yes I did, but I couldn't proceed any further :(

Comment: Take $x=y=z$ and any desired values for $a,b,c$ s.t. denominators are non-zero. Why do you think this should hold, with perhaps additional conditions disallowing equal $x,y,z$?

Comment: I do think this should hold because I checked with an arbitrary a, b, c; took a value of $x^2-yz$ and solved for x, y, and z (in wolframalpha). Though the solutions were complex, the R.T.P statement held.

Comment: I was actually trying to get a counter-example where this doesn't hold. But, unfortunately, didn't find one, so, posted it here.

Comment: Which one? Please state it.

Comment: you didn't read my first comment? Did you try it out? for e.g. $x=y=z=1, a=1, b=2,c=3$?

Comment: Oh! I misinterpreted your first comment @Macavity. Yes! That's a counterexample. But, that is type of forcing them to be equal by making the numerators zero.

Comment: Do you have a more general counterexample?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130830/discussion-between-asmit-karmakar-and-macavity).

Comment: @River Li In the case you are interested, I just wrote a solution.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks. I am unfamiliar with it. Is a complete detailed or step-by-step solution available?

Comment: Thanks everyone, just I am trying my best understanding the solutions (and to know the things necessary for doing so)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Jean Marie and @orangeskid gave very nice proofs.

Their idea, in algebraic manner, leads to the following proof:

We have the following identity
$$(p^2 - qr)^2 - (q^2 - rp)(r^2 - pq)
= p(p + q + r)(p^2 + q^2 + r^2 - pq - qr - rp).$$
Using this identity, we have
$$\frac{(x^2 - yz)^2 - (y^2 - zx)(z^2 - xy)}{(a^2 - bc)^2 - (b^2 - ca)(c^2 - ab)}
= k\,\frac{x}{a}, \tag{1}$$
and
$$\frac{(y^2 - zx)^2 - (z^2 - xy)(x^2 - yz)}{(b^2 - ca)^2 - (c^2 - ab)(a^2 - bc)}
= k\, \frac{y}{b}, \tag{2}$$
and
$$\frac{(z^2 - xy)^2 - (x^2 - yz)(y^2 - zx)}{(c^2 - ab)^2 - (a^2 - bc)(b^2 - ca)}
= k \, \frac{z}{c}, \tag{3}$$
where
$$k = \frac{(x + y + z)(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - xy - yz - zx)}{(a + b + c)(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - ab - bc - ca)}.$$
*Note*: One can prove $k \ne 0$.
See the remarks at the end.

We are done.

---

*Remarks*:

If $k = 0$, we have $x + y + z = 0$.
Using $z = -x - y$, we have
$$\frac{x^2 + xy + y^2}{a^2-bc}=\frac{x^2 + xy + y^2}{b^2-ca}=\frac{x^2 + xy + y^2}{c^2-ab} \ne 0$$
which results in
$a^2 - bc = b^2 - ca = c^2 - ab$
and thus $(a-b)(a + b + c) = 0$ and $(b - c)(a + b + c) = 0$.
Thus, $a = b = c$ which contradicts the given conditions.

Comment: This was the simplest one. Thanks.

Comment: The proof is due to @ Jean Marie and @ orangeskid.

Comment: You mentioned it in your answers, though I haven't figured out how their answers are equivalent to this one, still, I can only accept one answer, else I would have accepted them all :)

Comment: [+1] Just read your answer ! Thanks for it and thanks for the thanks...

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution that necessitates to have had a previous introduction

- to conic curves (maybe it is the case) and to
- barycentric coordinates (less likely, unless you have prepared some Mathematics Olympiads) ; [here](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Triangle/tricoords.html) or [here](https://web.evanchen.cc/handouts/bary/bary-short.pdf) are a nice introduction to barycentric coordinates (**b.c.** in short). One of the most elementary (and important) property is that b.c. are defined up to a multiplicative factor.

Indeed, for a fixed triangle of reference, your issue amounts to assert the bijectivity (one-to-one onto) of the following transformation,

$$M\underbrace{(x, \ y, \ z)}_{\text{b.c.}} \ \ \xrightarrow{(H)} \ \ M'\underbrace{(x^2-yz,\ \ y^2-zx, \ \ z^2-xy)}_{\text{b.c.}} \tag{1}$$

known as **Hirst transform** (see [here](https://bernard-gibert.pagesperso-orange.fr/Exemples/k296.html)).

This transformation can be defined geometrically: $M'$ is the intersection point of line $GM$ (where $G$ is the center of mass of the triangle) and polar line of $M$ with respect to the Steiner interior ellipse. See figure below and proof in the Appendix at the bottom.

[image]

*Fig. 1: Steiner ellipse (S), tangent to the triangle's sides in their midpoints. $G$ is the center of mass. Being given point $M$, its Hirst transform is $M'=(P) \cap GM$, where $(P)$ is the polar line of $M$ with respect to $(S)$ (in green). Please note that in this case of figure where $M$ is outside the ellipse, (P) has been obtained by connecting the tangency points of the tangents to (S) issued from $M$.*

Knowing $M'$, it is easy to retrieve its unique preimage $M$, establishing the bijectivity of Hirst transform $(H)$, even more its involutivity $(H)^{-1}=H$. This involutivity can be checked, of course, in an algebraic way.

Remarks :

1. Strictly speaking, we have to exclude the case where $M$ has identical barycentric coordinates $(x,y,z)$ with $x=y=z$, which means that $M$ is situated at the center of mass $G$ ; indeed, in this case, line $GM$ is undefined. It is a confirmation of the exceptional "counterexample" $x=y=z=1$ found by @Macavity.
2. See the very interesting analysis in the other answer by @orangeskid.
3. Hirst transform is mentioned but in a handful of texts such as [this one](http://home.citycable.ch/langfamille/PagesWEB/PedalCircleCenterTransformation.pdf) in connection with the study of certain cubic curves.
4. The "nonclassical" life of Mr Hirst is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Archer_Hirst).

**Appendix:** Proof of the geometrical interpretation:

The internal Steiner ellipse has equation:

$$x^2+y^2+z^2-2(xy+yz+zx)=0$$

which is equivalent to:

$$2(xy+yz+zx)=\frac12\tag{2}$$

(see [here](http://math.fau.edu/Yiu/YIUIntroductionToTriangleGeometry121226.pdf) p. 119). Therefore, the polar of point $(x,y,z)$, is given by the bilinear expression associated with quadratic form in the LHS of (2) has equation:

$$(x'y+y'x)+(y'z+z'y)+(z'x+x'z)=\frac12 \iff $$

$$x'(y+z)+y'(z+x)+z'(x+y)=\frac12\tag{3}$$

Besides, the equation of line $GM$ is:

$$\begin{vmatrix}1&x&x'\\1&y&y'\\1&z&z'\end{vmatrix}=0 \iff x'(z-y)+y'(x-z)+z'(y-x)=0\tag{4}$$

The intersection of straight lines given by (3) and (4) is obtained by solving the system (3)+(4), giving, up to a multiplicative constant (as always with b.c.) :

$$\begin{pmatrix}x'\\y'\\z'\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-x^2+yz\\-y^2+zx\\-z^2+xy\end{pmatrix}$$

as awaited.

Comment: I have calculated for the particular case when the triangle is equilateral.  I think your transformation is given in the barycentric coordinates wr to the midpoints triangle. SInce otherwise, you could have a point and its transform with all positive coordinates, not possible.  Also, perhaps it should follow from the geometric description that the transformation is an involution.

Comment: Taking as reference the midpoints' triangle would mean taking the outer Steiner ellipse instead of the inner one. Would it provide a big change ?

Comment: I guess the transformation should use barycentric coordinates w r to a triangle inscribed in the conic. That's what my calculations for the equilateral triangle tell me. So yes, I think it is the outer Steiner ellipse in fact. It it not that a big deal but note that the image of a point inside the triangle goes outside the triangle ( one of the expressions $x^2 - y z$, etc must be negative). So that's why it cannot be the inside Steiner.

Comment: Thank you very much for these observations. The negativity of some but not all of the expressions $x^2-yz$ (meaning of course being outside the triangle) shouldn't be harmful by I am going to have a closer look... Thanks again. Have a good day.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for the nice introduction of these concepts.

Answer (score 3):

An idea would be to show that if
$$[p\colon q\colon r] = [x^2 - y z \ \colon y^2 - x z\  \colon z^2 - x y]$$
then
$$[x\ \colon y \colon z] = [p^2 - q r\ \colon q^2 - p r\  \colon r^2 - p q]$$

In other words, the map from $\mathbb{P}^2$ to itself given by
$$[x\ \colon y \colon z]\mapsto [x^2 - y z \ \colon y^2 - x z\  \colon z^2 - x y]$$
is an involution.

This can be checked by a direct calculation. Alternatively, we can see that for the matrix
$$A = \left (\begin{matrix} x & y & z \\ y & z & x \\ z & x & y\end{matrix} \right)$$
the [adjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) matrix is of similar form
$$\operatorname{adj} A = \left (\begin{matrix} x^2 - y z  & y^2 - x z  & z^2 - x y \\ y^2 - x z  & z^2 - x y & x^2 - y z \\ z^2 - x y  & x^2 - y z  & y^2 - x z \end{matrix} \right)$$
and use the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix#Iterated_adjugates)
$$\operatorname{adj}\operatorname{adj}A = \det A \cdot A $$

Notice that
$$\det A = \frac{1}{2}(x+y+z) ((x-y)^2 + (y-z)^2 + (z-x)^2)$$

so according to the conditions in OP, it is $\ne 0$.

$\bf{Added:}$

Some calculations related to Hirst transform. Given a quadric $Q(p)=0$ and a point $p_0$ not on the quadric, to consider the "inversion" wr to $Q$ and center $p_0$. It is like the inversion wr to a sphere, but with a projective description. I am following @Jean Marie:

For a point $p$ in projective space, consider the intersection of the line $p_0p$ with the hyperplane polar to $p$. Denote by $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ the bilinear form giving $Q$. We have $\phi(p) = \alpha p_0 + \beta p$, such that
$$\alpha p_0 + \beta p \perp p$$

So we can take
$$\phi(p) = \langle p,p \rangle  p_0 - \langle p, p_0 \rangle p $$

Check that
$$\langle \phi(p), p \rangle = 0 \\
\langle \phi(p), p_0\rangle = G(p, p_0)\\
 \langle \phi(p), \phi(p)\rangle = G(p, p_0) \cdot \langle p, p\rangle $$
where $G(p, p_0)$ is the Gram determinant of $p$, $p_0$, which gives
$$\phi\circ \phi(p) = \langle p, p_0 \rangle\cdot G(p, p_0) \cdot p$$

so projectively $\phi$ is an involution.

Comment: [+1] Our 2 solutions have a common part (but for the geometrical interpretation in am going to illustrate by a figure). A little detail : you have twice "adj" in the last but one formula.

Comment: @Jean Marie: Yes, if you do twice adj to a matrix, you get it back, up to a constant

Comment: @Jean Marie: the exponent is $n-2$ in general. If you look at the degrees, on LHS the entries have degree $(n-1)^2$, so on RHS it should be $n\cdot (n-2) + 1$. Easiest way to figure out the correct exponent.

Comment: @Jean Marie: Ah, splendid! The pictures in the article look a bit like oil slicks.  I checked Mr Hirst.  Very interesting.  Thank you for all the good info!

Answer (score 1):

**Proof**:

First of all, clearly we have
$$ (a - b)^2 + (b - c)^2 + (c - a)^2 \ne 0. \tag{1}$$

Now, we split into two cases:

**Case** 1  $~ x = y$:

We have
$$\frac{x^2-xz}{a^2-bc}=\frac{x^2-zx}{b^2-ca}=\frac{z^2-x^2}{c^2-ab} \ne 0$$
which results in
\begin{align*}
 a^2 - bc &= b^2 - ca, \tag{2}\\
 x(c^2 - ab) &= - (z + x)(b^2 - ca). \tag{3}
\end{align*}
From (2), we have $(a - b)(a + b + c) = 0$
which results in $a = b$.
With this and (3), we have
$x(c^2 - a^2) = - (z + x)(a^2 - ca)$ or $(a - c)(az - cx) = 0$ which results in $az - cx = 0$ or $\frac{x}{a} = \frac{z}{c}$,
where we have used $a = b$ and (1) to get $a \ne c$.
Thus, we have
$\frac{x}{a}=\frac{y}{b}=\frac{z}{c}$.

**Case** 2 $~ x \ne y$:

Let
\begin{align*}
 f &= (a^2 - bc)(y^2 - zx) - (b^2 - ca)(x^2 - yz) \\
 &= Az + B,\\
 g &= (a^2 - bc)(z^2 - xy) - (c^2 - ab)(x^2 - yz) \\
 &= Cz^2 + Dz + E
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
 A &= -{a}^{2}x-acy+{b}^{2}y+bcx, \\
 B &= {a}^{2}{y}^{2}+ac{x}^{2}-{b}^{2}{x}^{2}-bc{y}^{2}, \\
 C &= a^2 - bc,\\
 D &= -aby+{c}^{2}y, \\
 E &= -{a}^{2}xy+ab{x}^{2}+bcxy-{c}^{2}{x}^{2}.
\end{align*}
We eliminate $z$ from the system of $f = g = 0$ as follows.
Let
$$h = Cz \cdot f - A\cdot g = (BC - AD)z - AE.$$
Then let
\begin{align*}
 F &=  (BC - AD)\cdot f - A \cdot h\\
  &= 
 A^2 E - ABD + B^2C\\
 &= - \frac18 (x - y) [3(x + y)^2 + (x - y)^2]  ( ay - bx )  ( a + b + c )  \\
 &\qquad \times ( a^2 - bc ) [(a - b)^2 + (b - c)^2 + (c - a)^2].
\end{align*}

From $F = 0$, using (1) and the given conditions, we have $ay - bx = 0$
or $\frac{x}{a} = \frac{y}{b}$.
Since $x \ne y$, we have $a \ne b$.
Using $x = \frac{a}{b}y$,
we have
$$f = - \frac {y (a - b)  [ 3(a + b)^2 + (a - b)^2] ( bz - cy) }{4 b^2} = 0
$$
which results in $bz = cy$ or $\frac{y}{b} = \frac{z}{c}$.
Thus, we have
$\frac{x}{a}=\frac{y}{b}=\frac{z}{c}$.

We are done.